# Need a Null value from Xamarin Entry Control when Empty

Tags: xamarin.forms

It seems when using a `Entry` control in Xamarin forms if its not touched then it returns `Null`. However, if the user enters anything then clears the control, it returns `string.Empty`

Ideally I want to just keep the `Null` value as these go into the Database and as you can imagine its not very consistent with `Null`s and empty strings.

What is the best way to achieve the goal of keeping the `Null` regardless if the control has been edited ?

I've considered Converters but this means adding them to all `Entry` controls, maybe doing something in the Data Access Layer... not sure what as wouldn't this mean extra code for all the properties.

Comment: why not create a custom Entry control that enforces the behavior that you want?

Comment: I had considered this but thought it overkill to convert string.Empty to Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***behavior***.

Code

```
public class EntryNullBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (sender is Entry entry)
        {
            if (args.NewTextValue != null && args.NewTextValue.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                entry.Text = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usgae in Xaml

```
xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:DummyTestApp.Behavior"
...
<Entry x:Name="MyNullEntry" HeightRequest="50" FontSize="Large">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behavior:EntryNullBehavior/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

**P.S.** Now I don't know what you consider overkill (*seeing your comment*) but this solution is elegant

Comment: Thanks for that. Since this will be used extensively throughout a large project, it needs to be easy to integrate without a ton of bloat added to the XAML code. Now, I thought of using a converter and actually started to implement it then hit a snag, some of the Entry controls were already using a Converter. So considering the facts, I think (up to now) Behaviors seem the way forwards.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up making a very simple custom control as since I required this function for all Entry controls it made no sense adding Behaviors to each one.

```
public class EntryEx : Entry
{
    protected override void OnTextChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(oldValue, newValue == string.Empty ? null : newValue);
    }
}
```

Thanks to Jason for the idea.

Comment: this is better but you said custom control is overkill so i had to write a behavior

Comment: on first consideration it seemed it was, but then implementing the behavior I soon realised it was actually more work and created more XAML code. Its the downside of a been a lone developer, I've got no-one to bounce ideas off :(